# Codeigniter mysql sum query

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
 $this->db->select('SUM(status = In Stock)As In Stock,SUM(status = Allocated)AS Allocated,SUM(status = Decommission) as Decommission,SUM(status = In transit)AS In Transit');
    // $this->db->from('assets');
     $this->db->group_by("assettype,location");
     $query = $this->db->get('assets');
```

Getting syntax error in the above query.
Kindly help

Comment: Who is returning the error message? `PHP` or `MySQL`? I mean, have you already tried to run the `query` only in `MySQL`?

Answer (score 0):

change
$this->db->select('SUM(status = "In Stock")As In_Stock,SUM(status = "Allocated")AS Allocated,SUM(status = "Decommission") as Decommission,SUM(status = "In transit")AS In_Transit');